# How to contribute align rules

Tags: align

I've been working on align-rules for Fortran 90 so that the built-in **align** and **align-current** functions do something useful. What would be the best way to make this code available for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the code and any instructions to Emacs for its inclusion, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Sending a patch is preferred.

Or you can make the code available from a GIT repository or at [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispArea). At Emacs Wiki you can just copy+paste the code into your web browser - no need to set anything up locally etc.

Comment: I've added a note on [Emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands) and made a [git repository](https://github.com/jannisteunissen/align-f90), thanks.

Comment: Ditto, although do consider `report-emacs-bug` as well. Helping to make things *just work* in Emacs by default is tremendously valuable.

Comment: What @phils said!